# Messenger app with group albums/posts and admin feature

Tags: android, chat, hosted

I have been using LINE messenger soley to communicate with my game buddies. Even though I have WhatsApp and Facebook messenger, I don't use them since they give away a lot of personal information to strangers I met in game. 
LINE messenger is becoming less secure since there is no admin feature in groups and anyone can remove anyone. Also there is a case of bots which can remove everyone from the group.

Hence I am looking for a chat app with features like group albums and group posts, with an admin feature. I am thinking like a simple chat app. Because there will be many players of different tech knowledge.

Platform: Android (though a multiplatform would be nice). I don't have a server.

Comment: Discord not an option?

Comment: How about Slack?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Telegram](https://telegram.org). It focuses on [security](https://telegram.org/faq#q-what-is-telegram-what-do-i-do-here) and is free.

It has group, can share files and has admin functionality for group. Check out more in the [FAQ](https://telegram.org/faq#groups-supergroups-and-channels).

There are client for Android and also other platforms.

No server is required.

Comment: Telegram is good. But it doesn't have a album or group post feature that is accessable to new joinees.

Comment: @JacobThazhath does the [channel](https://telegram.org/faq_channels) function fits what you want?

Comment: partially. Need the same feature where anyone in the group can create posts and the admin can handle it. Sorry for the late reply.